# Zookeeper-shell is Returning null for broker requests

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

### Background

On my Kubernetes cluster, I have installed Zookeeper & Kafka using Confluent Operator. I have confirmed that they are configured properly by creating and publishing to a Kafka topic.

### Problem

When I use the zookeeper-shell, the command:
`get /brokers/ids` returns null, while I'm expecting something like [0, 1, 2]

### Details

I am using the zookeeper-shell from within the Kubernetes cluster, and am connecting without difficulty with the following command:
`~/bin/zookeeper-shell zookeeper:2181`

The following commands output the correct (non-null) response: `get /zookeeper/config`, `get /cluster/id`

But the following commands return null: `get /brokers/ids`, `get /brokers/topics`

### More Info

The fact that I know the brokers are working makes this strange. It could be a security issue, but it seems strange that the other requests would work in that case. Finally, Confluent Control Center is directly telling me that broker.id 1 is the controller, which implies that this data is somehow retrievable. Any help here would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. In the brokers' server.properties, zookeeper.connect was set to localhost:PORT instead of zookeeper:PORT